# Git: How to commit local changes after a reverse merge

Tags: git, merge, commit, reverse

Current situation:

Two developers are working in the **same remote** branch titled Sprint1:

Developer 1: Changes some code in say 2 files, commits (accidentally adding 3 other files as well), and pushes to Sprint1.

Developer 2: Realizes somehow Developer 1 also accidentally added 3 files we did not want pushed. So he Reverse-merges the changes back to the commit before Developer 1's changes.

At this point Developer 1 wants to attempt to commit his two files again (and not the extra 3 which he is still working on) and push to the remote branch (Sprint1). The problem is a pull will overwrite Developers 1 local files and effectively "delete" his local changes in all 5 files.

What is the proper way for Developer 1 to get to the up to date head but to be able to push the correct files this time without losing the changes?

Comment: What do you mean by a "reverse merge"?  A reset or a revert?

Comment: Git never "delete" data, Dev1 will have to merge his desired changes back to the new HEAD of Sprint1, at worst scenario he'll be left with some conflicts.

Comment: I just wanted to add a bit of helpful advice to avoid these types of problems. I highly recommend having each dev work on their own temporary dev branches and then merge back into the main dev branch once they have completed some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing about git is that it's pretty hard to completely delete smth you once commited. If you don't want to perform force push to the repository in order to remove both these commits (the original one and the one that reverted it) and commit your changes from scratch there's what  Developer 1 can do:

1. `git pull` - ok, we pull the revert commit and have history like that:

   ```
   ca798ca revert 'commit1'
   cf76cf7 commit1
   ```

   Well, we 'lost' our changes, but don't worry - next step will bring them back.
2. `git revert -n HEAD` (or explicit `git revert -n ca798ca`) to revert revert commit. Now all the changes from the original commit (both necessary and unnecessary changes) are in the index, but not yet commited (thanks to `-n` option).
3. `git reset HEAD` to move all the changes from the index back into the working directory.
4. `git add necessary_file && git commit -m 'necessary changes'` to add only necessary changes to index and commit them. All the changes you don't want in this commit will stay in your working directory.
5. `git push` to share your results with the colleague.

These steps are provided AS IS, so if you don't understand something from the above, please, ask before doing it. Otherwise, things might become even more messy.

Comment: This worked very well with the explicit revision at step 2. I then wanted to figure it out via a GUI (SmartGit) but was unable to figure out how to do the same thing that way? Thanks for the solution @KL-7!

Answer (score 1):

Have Developer 1 create another branch with his current local edits and then make a pull request on the Sprint1 branch on his local file to his Sprint1 branch (not the new branch he created). He can then run `git rm` on the three files he didn't want committed in the new branch, and then merge that branch back into Sprint1.